# 2018 Nissan Sentra with 50k miles needs struts one side. Can I replace only one side

Tags: nissan, struts, sentra

I have 2018 Nissan Sentra with 50k miles. Hit curb and one side Front struts bent. Can I Replace only one side?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate question ... in fact, I'm pretty sure I'm the one who answered it. I'll have to look and see.

Comment: Well, I didn't answer it, but it almost identical.

Comment: I hit a curb with a 2011 Nissan Murano ; No problem for the struts but i bent the aluminum  "A" frame, Dealer replaced the A frame and it has been fine for 70,000 miles ( total miles 85,000).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the other side to the damaged one has never been replaced (i.e. it has done the full 50k) I'd say you'd be best off replacing both sides together.

While the wear on the remaining side won't be ridiculous I think it will be enough that the imbalance between the two will start putting additional strain on other suspension components and will likely affect the handling to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question..... Yes you can.
Is it a good idea?  Not really.

For a more comprehensive answer, It's not a good idea to replace wear items on one side of a vehicle. At some point the original strut will need to be replaced anyway and then you'll be in the same situation again. Aside from that, the front end components of a vehicle are engineered to be symmetrical. Replacing only one side can lead to stability problems and potentially put additional load on other components.

In fact, I would be surprised if a shop would even agree to just replace one side.  If the vehicle was almost new, the answer would most likely be different.